# Can't logout from facebook in ios app swift (Firebase Authentication + Facebook)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication and database for user signup/login in my application. Facebook login is successfully integrated in my app and working well. Now I am trying to logout from app. Again trying to login with diffrence account but it still display app permission screen in webview. Inshort I **can't logout completely**. I want to login with diffrence account.I can't login with another account untill delete/uninstall the app.

**What I tried out:**

-Clear the session

-Firebase signout method called

-facebook logout method called

-also logout from safari and facebook app which is installed in my device.

-Delete the app permission programmatically

**Here is my code:**

```
 FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrent(nil)

 FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()

  try!  Auth.auth().signOut()
```

**also tried:**

```
   let deletepermission = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/permissions/", parameters: nil, httpMethod: "DELETE")
        deletepermission?.start(completionHandler: { (connect, result, error) in
            print("the delete permission is \(result)")
        })
```

**Still it shows this screen after logout, when try to again login:**

[image]

It sucks me I don't know what I forgot here or something issue while try to logout from facebook with firebase.

Please help/suggestion

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the code you use to sign out ?

Comment: code is added @mazen